# android application crash when i try to open activity

Tags: java, android

every time i try to open a business my apa crashes
I want the app to send the data present in the input text
via url to be able to take them via a php script
do you have any solution?
I have tried several changes but nothing works for now
I don't understand where the mistake can be, any help?

it's probably a simple stupid mistake, but one I can't find. I've attached java, xml file, and logcat.

java code:

```
 String nomep;
int prezzop, tempop;
Button btnInserisci;
RadioButton aggiorna;
RadioButton servizio;
RadioButton ricambio;
RadioButton accessori;
EditText nome;
EditText prezzo;
EditText tempo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inserisci);

    aggiorna = findViewById(R.id.aggiorna);
    servizio = findViewById(R.id.servizio);
    ricambio = findViewById(R.id.ricambio);
    accessori = findViewById(R.id.acessori);
    nome = findViewById(R.id.nomeProdotto);
    prezzo = findViewById(R.id.prezzo);
    tempo = findViewById(R.id.tempo);

    //pulsante in ascolto del "click"
    btnInserisci = findViewById(R.id.scanInserisci);
    btnInserisci.setOnClickListener(this);
    scan();

}

//se il pulsante viene cliccato apre la funzione "scan"
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    scan();

}


private void scan(){

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scannerizzando il codice..");
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents() != null){
           if(aggiorna.isChecked()) {
               if(accessori.isChecked()){
                   //stringa sito da cambiare con quella del server funzionante

                   String sito = "https://www.gorinsights.it/scuola/server.php?nuovo=no&aggiungi=si&tabella=accessori&id=" + result.getContents();
                   gotoUrl(sito);


               }else if (ricambio.isChecked()){
                   //stringa sito da cambiare con quella del server funzionante
                   String sito = "https://www.gorinsights.it/scuola/server.php?nuovo=no&aggiungi=si&tabella=ricambio&id=" + result.getContents();
                   gotoUrl(sito);

               }else if (servizio.isChecked()){

                   Toast.makeText(this,"non puoi aggiungere quantità ad un servizio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }else{

                   Toast.makeText(this,"scegli dove aggiornare il prodotto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }







           }else{

               if(accessori.isChecked()){
                   nomep = nome.getText().toString();
                   prezzop = Integer.valueOf(prezzo.getText().toString());

                   //stringa da aggiustare
                   String sito = "https://www.gorinsights.it/scuola/server.php?nuovo=si&tabella=accessori&id=" + result.getContents()+"&nome="+nomep+"&prezzo="+prezzop;
                   gotoUrl(sito);



               }else if (ricambio.isChecked()){
                   nomep = nome.getText().toString();
                   prezzop = Integer.valueOf(prezzo.getText().toString());

                   //stringa da aggiustare
                   String sito = "https://www.gorinsights.it/scuola/server.php?nuovo=si&tabella=ricambio&id=" + result.getContents()+"&nome="+nomep+"&prezzo="+prezzop;
                   gotoUrl(sito);


               }else if (servizio.isChecked()){
                   nomep = nome.getText().toString();
                   prezzop = Integer.valueOf(prezzo.getText().toString());
                   tempop=Integer.valueOf(tempo.getText().toString());

                   //stringa da aggiustare
                   String sito = "https://www.gorinsights.it/scuola/server.php?nuovo=si&tabella=servizio&id=" + result.getContents()+"&nome="+nomep+"&prezzo="+prezzop+"&tempo="+tempop;
                   gotoUrl(sito);


               }else{

                   Toast.makeText(this,"scegli dove inserire il prodotto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }

           }

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"nessun risultato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void gotoUrl(String sito) {



    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sito);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Here we use an intent without a Chooser unlike the next example
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context=".inserisci">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanInserisci"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="scan"
    android:translationX="400px"
    android:translationY="1500px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/aggiungi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aggiungi nuovo"
    android:translationX="100px"
    android:translationY="200px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/servizio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="servizio"
    android:translationX="750px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/ricambio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ricambio"
    android:translationX="400px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/acessori"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="acessori"
    android:translationX="80px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/aggiorna"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aggiorna quantià"
    android:translationX="600px"
    android:translationY="200px" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="500px"
    android:id="@+id/nomeProdotto">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="nome prodotto" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="700px"
    android:id="@+id/prezzo"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="prezzo" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="1000px"
    android:id="@+id/tempo"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="tempo necessario (obbligatorio solo per i servizi)" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

crash log:

```
2021-01-26 13:46:47.709 8672-8672/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.scanner, PID: 8672
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scanner/com.example.scanner.inserisci}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:868)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.scanner.inserisci.onCreate(inserisci.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".inserisci">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanInserisci"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="scan"
    android:translationX="400px"
    android:translationY="1500px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/aggiungi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aggiungi nuovo"
    android:translationX="100px"
    android:translationY="200px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/servizio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="servizio"
    android:translationX="750px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/ricambio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ricambio"
    android:translationX="400px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/acessori"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="acessori"
    android:translationX="80px"
    android:translationY="350px" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/aggiorna"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aggiorna quantià"
    android:translationX="600px"
    android:translationY="200px" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="500px">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/nomeProdotto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="nome prodotto" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="700px">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/prezzo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="prezzo" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="1000px">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tempo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="tempo necessario (obbligatorio solo per i servizi)" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error message says it all:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: com.google.android.material.textfield.**TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup**

You are trying to cast a `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` to an EditText, they're not the same thing:

inside onCreate you have :

```
nome = findViewById(R.id.nomeProdotto);
```

you have defined this as

```
EditText nome; <-- this is defined in your activity
```

but in your xml you have

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout <-- this is defined in your xml
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="500px"
    android:id="@+id/nomeProdotto">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="nome prodotto" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---

what you probably wanted to do was something like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="500px">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nomeProdotto"
        android:hint="nome prodotto" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```